# How can we prove that electric field originate from and terminate on charge using Gauss Law?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electricity, charge

We already know that electric field originate and terminate on charge only and they doesn't make any closed path. But is it possible to prove this statement using Gauss Law ? If yes then how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Gauss' law does imply that the electric field terminates only on charges, it certainly does not imply that it cannot form closed paths. Gauss' law may be expressed as follows:
$$\nabla\cdot\mathbf{E} = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$$
From the [Helmholtz theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition) of vector calculus, as any vector can be expressed in terms of two parts ($\phi$ and $\mathbf{A}$ are not to be confused with the potentials):
$$\mathbf{E} = \nabla\phi + \nabla\times\mathbf{A}$$
But since $\nabla\cdot\nabla\times\mathbf{A} = 0$ always, $\nabla\cdot\mathbf{E} = \nabla^2\phi$. Thus, Gauss' law does not say anything about $\mathbf{A}$, and we can choose it so that the field lines form closed paths.

The question of closed paths is taken care of by the [Maxwell-Faraday equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday's_law_of_induction#Maxwell.E2.80.93Faraday_equation):
$$\nabla\times\mathbf{E} = -\frac{\partial\mathbf{B}}{\partial t}$$
where $\mathbf{E}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are the electric and magnetic fields.

When $\mathbf{B} = 0$ at all points, at all times, then we have the following (electrostatic) form:
$$\nabla\times\mathbf{E} = 0$$

It is more intuitive to convert this to integral form using [Stokes' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem#Kelvin.E2.80.93Stokes_theorem):
$$\oint \mathbf{E}\cdot\mathbf{ds} = 0$$

This states that the integral of the tangential component of the electric field around any closed loop is always zero in electrostatics. In other words, the electric field lines can't form closed paths in the case of electrostatics.

Comment: Nicely put.  Note that this is often a sticking point when students learn about the $\vec{D}$ field, which satisfies a version of Gauss's Law ($\nabla \cdot \vec{D} = \rho_f$) but whose curl does not, in general, vanish.  Field lines for $\vec{D}$ can therefore look quite different than those for $\vec{E}$, even for the same charge distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Gauss law states that electric flux through a closed surface equals $\frac{q}{\epsilon_0}$, where $\epsilon_0$ is a constant and $q$ is the charge contained in the surface. So, if we corner a 'point charge' using a spherical closed surface, with the charge at the center of the sphere, all we have to do is to start reducing the radius of the sphere.

Because the value of 'flux' emanating out of the sphere is $\frac{q}{\epsilon_0}$, which is positive in our case of the point charge, as we go on decreasing the radius to make it $0$, the value of flux will remain the same even for a very small sphere around the point charge. Hence it is clear that the flux, and hence electric field, must be coming out of the point charge...